# Blazor Server App does not require all users to Authenticate

Tags: asp.net, blazor

My Blazor Server app is working fine BUT it seems to remember the last user who logged in (using Windows AD) and thinks everyone afterwards is that user. Subsequent users do not get asked to log in. As I understand it, Server App does not use cookies but it obviously has some sort of cache to remember a user. **How do I force it to Authorize every new user making a request?**

Using 'Authentication Type: Windows' for the project and this code in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
    NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.FallbackPolicy = new 
      AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

This is the code which always returns the last logged in user:

```
var authState = await 
   AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the above code in the shared folder that will cause the logged user issues.
Follow these steps to resolve the issue.

1. Create a new service and call the getusername() function.
2. Then call that service in your razor.cs file to retrieve username.

Comment: Thanks. The code is in program.cs and index.razor so not in the shared folder. But I'd like to persue your suggestion. When you say create a new service what kind of service do you mean? Can you provide a code snippet illustrating how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new folder in your project &
Create a new class file and have the following code
[ADAuthService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqVXh.png)

2.In your razor page, call the ADAuthservice in OnInitializedAsync() function.

Comment: I installed your suggestions. Site is still not asking me to log in but then I am the last person to log in. We shall see tomorrow when I can ask one of the other guys at work if it still assumes he is me or asks him to log in.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had failed to add the following code to the top of app.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
...
   <AuthorizeRouteView ...>
```

Of-course if you just select 'Authentication Type: Windows' this code is all added automatically to your new project. But I was trying to retrofit 'Authentication Type : Windows' generated code from a new project into my older/legacy website project and I missed copying that piece.